# Explain how the partition $A_{i}$ is chosen to make this chain of equalities true

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

If there is only positive measure at a discrete point $\omega_{i} \in \Omega$, $i = 1, 2, \cdots$, then for any function defined on $(\Omega,\mu)$, $$\int f d\mu = \int_{\Omega}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} f(\omega) I_{A_{i}}(\omega) d\mu = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} f(\omega_{i})\mu(\{ \omega_{i} \}) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f(\omega_{i})\mu(\{ \omega_{i} \})  $$

What I need to do is, I need to clearly define my $A_{0},A_{1}, A_{2}, \cdots$ so that the above equalities are true, and I also need to explain why we are allowed to ignore the $0$th term in the infinite sum to give us the last equality.

However, I am not sure how to do this. I'm thinking that if we chose the $A_{0}, A_{1}, A_{2}, \cdots $ to be disjoint, and each contain its corresponding $\omega_{i}$, then we would get the middle equality. But, I'm not sure how to formally say this. Also, I have no idea how to get the last equality, unless somehow $\mu(\{\omega_{0}\}) = 0$...

Could somebody please help me finish this? Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Yeap. There is no such term $\omega_0$ in $\Omega$ so $\mu(\{\omega_0\})=0$ and the term vanishes

Comment: @GrahamKemp well, that answers that question then. Interesting that I missed that. What about for the rest of it? How do I choose my partitions $A_{i}$ in order to get the equalities above?

Comment: @GrahamKemp are you still around? Can you give an answer to this?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you choose the partitions; each of the discrete points with positive measure will belong to one (and only one) of the partitions.

Comment: @GrahamKemp my professor said something like "rephrase $f$ by using simple measurable functions by picking out suitable $A_{0}$, $A_{1}$. etc." Do you know what he meant by that? Perhaps he's saying this is how you show the left-most equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only a countable amount of discrete points in the sample space $\Omega$ have positive (non-zero) measure, it does not matter how you partition $\Omega$; each one of these discrete points will belong to one, and only one, of the countable many partitions.

$\displaystyle\qquad\int_\Omega f(\omega)\,\sum_{i=0}^\infty\mathbf 1_{A_i}(\omega)\;\mathrm d\,\mu ~{~=~\sum_{j=1}^\infty f(\{\omega_j\})\,\mu(\{\omega_j\})\,\sum_{i=0}^\infty \mathbf 1_{A_i}(\omega_j) \\ ~=~\sum_{j=1}^\infty f(\{\omega_j\})\,\mu(\{\omega_j\})}$

Comment: one more thing though is: Why is $\int_{\Omega} f(\omega) \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 1_{A_{i}} (\omega) d \mu = \int_{\Omega} f(\omega) d\mu$ in this case? As in how does the $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 1_{A_{i}}(\omega)$ weasel its way in? Is it because only countably many discrete points have positive measure that we're allowed to say that?